# Can you set an xml node to a variable in SSIS?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, ssis

Pretty straightforward question.  I want to set an xml node to a SSIS variable and use that variable as an input parameter.  Is this possible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where you xml is. If it is in database then you can use the  following code in Execute SQL Task.

```
declare @xFull xml = 
'
<a>
    <b u="1"> 
        <c d="asd"/>
    </b>
</a>
'
declare @node xml;

select
@node = n.query('.')
from @xFull.nodes('/a/b') as f(n)

select convert(varchar(2000),@node) as node
```

Set `ResultSet` to `Single row` and create Result Set mapping to parameter like below:
[image: Result set to parameter mapping]
For execution stored procedure use another SQL Task. Set the statement like below:

```
exec test @xml=?
```

Then map input parameter:
[image]

Comment: How do I execute the stored procedure? I tried using SQL Source Type -"direct input" and it is not letting me use the execute command.

Comment: Thank you that seemed to work.  One last question.  How would I setup the data type and value of the initial variable "v1"?

Comment: You can do it in `Variables` view. If I help you? accept my answer or up it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So set the variable "v1" to string and leave the value blank?

Comment: Getting error when i set "exec Test @x" in the sql statement that says - "must declare scalar variable "@x"

Comment: Oh, yes! I edit my answer one more time! Look at last picture and query they have been changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75018/discussion-between-dc922-and-vladimir-semashkin).